# Modifying 2D array elements

Tags: ruby, multidimensional-array, array-initialization

Basically I'm trying to modify an element in a 2D array. How the array is initialized seems to be effecting the behaviour. I'm new to Ruby so I'm not sure how initializing an array would effect this. What am I missing to get the desired result from the desired initialization method?

```
arr_1 = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]] # undesired initialization
arr_2 = Array.new(3, Array.new(3, 0)) # desired initialization

arr_1[0][0] = 99
puts arr_1 # desired result below
=begin
99
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
=end

arr_2[0][0] = 99
puts arr_2 # undesired result
=begin
99
0
0
99
0
0
99
0
0
=end
```

Comment: You have to use `Array.new(3) { Array.new(3, 0) }` if you want multiple copies – see [`Array::new` – Common gotchas](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Array.html#method-c-new-label-Common+gotchas)

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick (:

Comment: Note: `arr_2 = Array.new(3, Array.new(3, 0))` then `arr_2.map { |a| a.object_id } #=> [1420, 1420, 1420]`. What does that tell you?

Comment: If the elements in the array were unique from each other, the object id would differ?